# How to join KStream and GlobalKTable?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-streams

I am looking to join one of my streams with a GlobalKTable, and I am running into problems in the process.  I have 3 topics I am listening too.  An update-raw topic, an update topic, and a session topic.

My update-raw topic's stream translates an un-serialized update request to a serialized request([String, String] -> [String,Update]).  This is than pushed to my update topic.

```
val updateTransformStore = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("updateTransformState")
val updateTransformStoreBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(updateTransformStore,stringSerde,updateSerde)
builder.addStateStore(updateTransformStoreBuilder)

val rawUpdateStream = builder.stream("update-raw", Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String,Serdes.String))
    .filter((_,value) => filterUpdateRequest(value))

rawUpdateStream.transform(updateTransformer,"updateTransformState")
    .to("update-stream",Produced.`with`(stringSerde,updateSerde))
```

My update topic is a GlobalKTable.

```
val globalMaterialized: Materialized[String,UpdateInfo,KeyValueStore[Bytes, Array[Byte]]] = Materialized.as("global-update-store").withKeySerde(stringSerde).withValueSerde(updateSerde)
val updateTable: GlobalKTable[String,UpdateInfo] = builder.globalTable("update-stream", globalMaterialized)
```

My final topic is my session topic

```
val kvMapper = new KeyValueMapper[String, String, String] {
  override def apply(key: String, value: String): String = {
    val jsonVal = new ObjectMapper().readTree(value).asInstanceOf[ObjectNode]
    val session = jsonVal.findValue("session").findValue("id").toString replaceAll( "\"", "")
    session
  }
}
val vJoiner = new ValueJoiner[String,UpdateInfo,JsonWithUpdateInfo] {
  override def apply(value1: String, value2: UpdateInfo): JsonWithUpdateInfo = {
    if(value2 == null) {
      JsonWithUpdateInfo(value1,0,"default")
    }
    else {
      JsonWithUpdateInfo(value1, value2.info1, value2.info2)
    }
  }
}
val filteredStream = builder.stream("session", Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String, Serdes.String))
  .filter((_, value) => filterRequest(value))

val joinedStream:KStream[String,JsonWithUpdateInfo] = filteredStream.join(updateTable,kvMapper,vJoiner)

joinedStream.print(stringSerde,jsonSerde)
```

After pushing one update and one session onto the respective topics, my program seems to stop execution after the `filteredStream.join` tries to execute.  My print never works, nor do any attempts to run further commands run.  Throwing debug prints in my kvMapper and vJoiner also do no produce output.  Is there anything I am missing when trying to join this table and stream?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(From the conversation in the comment section above)

If you have any `null` keys or values, those would be dropped.

In order to trace the call chain, you might want to set a breakpoint on `KStreamKTableJoinProcessor#process()` to see what the `join` operator actually does.

(The OP) Seems that was the problem, I wasn't aware I needed to have a key at point of joining. My mapper used part of the value to join the table, so I figured a null key was fine, applied a transform right before the join and it works as expected.